# Abstract published but no link to full paper

Tags: abstract

I just came across this publication (link below) in the AHA journal. it has a summary/abstract of the research but no link to the full research paper. Would anyone be able to explain the reasoning behind this.

https://www.ahajournals.org/doi/10.1161/str.49.suppl_1.180

Answer (score 1):

There's no full paper associated to that abstract, because it's a conference abstract, not a paper abstract. If you go up one level from that link you'll find:

[International Stroke Conference Oral Abstracts](https://www.ahajournals.org/toc/str/49/Suppl_1)

That is a collection of the abstracts of the works presented at that conference. This is common in some conferences: authors submit only a short description of their work, typically half or one page long. In the past, these submission were typically collected in a *book of abstracts* which was given to the participants at the beginning of the conference. Nowadays, abstracts are more commonly distributed in electronic form.

Comment: Note that the presentation may well have covered material from one or more recent papers by the author.  One can search for those papers.